# How to auto-resize main pane after inserting dynamically GridPane

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javafx, scenebuilder

I have AnchorPane which is the Main that has all other panes.
Inside it I have the board area which is AnchorPane and area for the dice which is also AnchorPane. 
This is how it looks on scene builder:
[image]

inside the board Area which is AnchorPane I am creating dynamically (according to the user request) the size of the board (5x5, 6x6, 7x7 or 8x8):

```
  GridPane boardGame;

    @FXML
    Button dice;

    @FXML
    AnchorPane boardArea;

    @FXML
    AnchorPane boardGameAnchorPane;

    @FXML
    AnchorPane dicePane;

 public void CreateBoard()
    {
       int boardSize = m_Engine.GetBoard().GetBoardSize();
       int num = 1;
       int maxColumns = m_Engine.GetNumOfCols();
       int maxRows = m_Engine.GetNumOfRows();
       boardGame = new GridPane();
       //boardGame.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

       for(int row = maxRows - 1; row >= 0 ; row--)
       {
             for(int col =  0; col < maxColumns ; col++)
             {
                StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
                stackPane.setMaxSize(SIZE_OF_CELL, SIZE_OF_CELL);
                stackPane.setMinSize(SIZE_OF_CELL, SIZE_OF_CELL);

                if((col + row) % 2 != 0)
                {
                     stackPane.getStyleClass().add("oddCellBorder");
                }
                else
                {
                    stackPane.getStyleClass().add("evenCellBorder");
                }

                Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(num));
                StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
                stackPane.getChildren().add(label);

                boardGame.add(stackPane, col, row);
                num++;
            }
       }

       this.fixBoardGameSize();
       boardGame.setGridLinesVisible(true);
      // boardGame.autosize();
       boardArea.getChildren().add(boardGame);

       //ImageView imageView = ImageUtils.getImageView("diceTransprntBack3D.png");
       //dice.setGraphic(imageView);
       // Image img1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("about.png"));
    }
```

My problem starts from board size of 7x7 or 8x8.
The board area spread to the dice area:
[image]

I tried to fix the sizes manually with this function:

```
private void fixBoardGameSize()
{
    boardArea.setMinHeight(boardGame.getHeight());
    boardArea.setMaxHeight(boardGame.getHeight());
    boardArea.setMinWidth(boardGame.getWidth());
    boardArea.setMaxWidth(boardGame.getWidth());

   boardGameAnchorPane.setPrefWidth(boardArea.getWidth() + dicePane.getWidth() + 500 );
   boardGameAnchorPane.setMinWidth(boardArea.getWidth() + dicePane.getWidth() + 500 );
   boardGameAnchorPane.setMaxWidth(boardArea.getWidth() + dicePane.getWidth() + 500 );
   dicePane.setLayoutX(boardArea.getLayoutX() + boardArea.getWidth() + 1000);
}
```

But with no success.
I tried also to play with the anchor pain constraint with no success.
I searched but can't find something that can help me so I am asking here if someone knows how I can keep the two anchor panes separated.

Comment: You should define a maximum size for the board and then calculate and define the size of each element based on the percentage of its area.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, using the same anchor panes, and given a fixed size of your application, what you can do is:

First, set a maximum size for the boardArea, a margin for the grid to be correctly displayed on that pane

```
// Maximum fixed size you give to boardArea
public static final double MAX_SIZE = 600;

// Margin to border
public static final double MARGIN = 25;
```

And now, in your `fixBoardGameSize()` method, resize properly the grid:

```
private void fixBoardGameSize(){
    // Listener, since boardGame dimensions are determined after the stage is shown
    ChangeListener<Number> resize = (ov, v, v1) -> {
        double scale = Math.min((MAX_SIZE - 2d*MARGIN) / boardGame.getWidth(), 
                                (MAX_SIZE - 2d*MARGIN) / boardGame.getHeight());
        boardGame.setScaleX(scale);
        boardGame.setScaleY(scale);
        boardGame.setTranslateX((MAX_SIZE - boardGame.getWidth()) / 2d);
        boardGame.setTranslateY((MAX_SIZE - boardGame.getHeight()) / 2d);
    };

    boardGame.widthProperty().addListener(resize);
    boardGame.heightProperty().addListener(resize);
}
```

Now you can display games with any number of rows and columns. It will always fit in the board, and it will be properly centered.